# Cloudpage UpsertData publish problem

Tags: marketing-cloud, upsert

I am struggling with some `UpsertData` and i am running out of options. Hope you can see the problem. I have the following script on a CloudPage with a SmartCapture form:

```
%%[

SET @DE1 = "Martijn_content_nb_form_test"


SET @email = RequestParamater("email")
SET @urlArtikel3Consument = RequestParamater("urlArtikel3Consument")

IF NOT EMPTY("email") THEN
UpsertDE(@DE1, 1, "email",@email, 
"urlArtikel3Consument",@urlArtikel3Consument)

ENDIF
]%%
```

When I publish the page it remains polling and i could not publish the page. It happens on the RequestParameter because when i delete that part i can publish. Is there something i miss? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a typo: 
RequestParamater should be **RequestParameter** written with E.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm

Comment: ahhhh thanks man! Didn't see that. One step further because it stil don't update an existing record.

Answer (score 0):

Should be UpsertDATA.  UpsertDE is for an email.  UpsertDATA is for CloudPage.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Unfortunately he only insert a new record and when i try a record allready exists he don't submit my form.

Comment: does your dataextension has a primary column, that won't allow multiple records with the same data? @TomCallahan shouldnt it be 8InsertData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/insertdata.htm) instead of UpsertData?

Comment: Yes the email field is the primary key but i thought that is the way to go? Strange thing is that when i change UpsertData to InsertData i can not publish my page. Does it has anything to do with the way i created the page? I mean with the new editor or the classic one?

Comment: I did some test with these results:

1. No primary keys. Now i can use the same emailaddress over and over again but it don't update the record. Instead it is every time a new record.
2. I use a combination of primary keys. I can use the same emailaddres but as soon the combination of the two primary keys are the same i can not submit my form. The other records are again new records.

So no succes yet in how i can update a record instead of adding new records.

Comment: UpsertDATA adds or updates the Data Extension row referenced in the column and value arguments. Values updated are specified with column name and value pairs. If no record matches the values specified, a new row is added. This function does not return a value.   InsertData inserts a row in a Data Extension with the specified column name and value pairs.  Have you taken your cloudpage html/ampscript and dropped it into an email for debugging purposes yet?

Comment: Is it mayby because my DE has more attrtibutes than i set up in my UpsertData?

Comment: Hi Tom, i run a test in a test email. I changed my UpsertDATA to UpsertDE because of the email. I did not get any errors.

Comment: Don't want any new records?  Then use `UpdateDATA`.